# Updating Tkinter GUI while running a thread using concurrent futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, concurrent.futures

I am trying to update the GUI of my application using the result from a thread. But the application just freezes and does not respond. It does not even reach the open dialog box part.

```
def start_download():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        task = executor.submit(download)
        res = task.result()
    
    status.set(res)

def download():
    URL = url.get()
    is_valid = is_valid_url(URL)
    if not is_valid:
        return "Invalid URL"
    
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if path == "":
        return "Invalid Directory!"
    
    yt = YouTube(URL)
    streams = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension="mp4")
    highest_res = streams.get_highest_resolution()
    highest_res.download(output_path=path)

    return "Downloaded Succesfully!"
```

The start_download() function is called upon pressing a button. Thanks!

I tried using threading module at first but realised that it did not return any values from the thread. You can make a value return by defining your own thread on top of the pre existing one but it is more convenient to use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(). But now the application just does not respond.

Comment: `task.result()` blocks until the result is available. This blocks the whole application. As far as I know, this isn't an officially supported way but `download` could instead call [`after_idle`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112021403id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after_idle-method) method after download with an appropriate callback which is then executed in tkinter's main thread.